# ImageMagick - RBG to .jpg

Tags: imagemagick

I am new to ImageMagick.

I want to convert RGB color hex code or decimal code  example (#FF0000 or (255,0,0)) red to .jpg file. When I open the output .jpg file should be able see red color.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create an image that is all red?

Answer (score 1):

convert -size 400x400^ xc:#F4F2EA -quality 100 image.jpg

I got it thanks.